# "Ghost" values in PHP/Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I've been working on a site for a while changing the layout and skin of a webshop checkout process. I've noticed that if you go *all the way through* the process until the last page, then click the link to go back to the view products page, the delivery method price displays underneath the navigation buttons, until you refresh and it goes away again.

I've downloaded both sources from the browser (Chrome, but this bug applies to all browsers) and used a [file difference tool](http://www.ranks.nl) to display the differences, the result being only:

```
< error.html 
vs
> normal.html
34c34
<   <link href="gzip.php?file=167842c1496093fbcd391b41cf7b03da.css&time=1272272181" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
---
>   <link href="gzip.php?file=167842c1496093fbcd391b41cf7b03da.css&time=1272272348" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Which is just the way it zips up the CSS stylesheets. (afaik)

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem, or anything similar?

Normal:
[image: How it is meant to look]

Error:
[image: The weird bug]

I can't even hazard a guess as to what is causing this, at all. I've searched over Google for anything and come up with nothing.

There isn't even any markup in this sourcecode to display the leveringsmåte (Delivery method) div.

What could be causing this?

The site in question is [Euroworker.no](http://euroworker.no).

[HTML @ Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TRnNDnUU).

Smarty snippet:

```
{if !$CANONICAL}
        {canonical}{self}{/canonical}
    {/if}

    <link rel="canonical" href="{$CANONICAL}" />

    <!-- Css includes -->
    {includeCss file="frontend/Frontend.css"}
    {includeCss file="backend/stat.css"}

    {if {isRTL}}
        {includeCss file="frontend/FrontendRTL.css"}
    {/if}

    {compiledCss glue=true nameMethod=hash}
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <link href="stylesheet/frontend/FrontendIE.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        {if $ieCss}
            <link href="{$ieCss}" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        {/if}
    <![endif]-->
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Just used DOM Inspector and found this:

```
<TD class="amount shippingAmount">138.-</TD>
```

Which is in the last page of the process.. Why would this be carrying over?

**UPDATE 2**

Got this from NET tab in Firebug,

```
GET order

Response Headersview source
Date    Mon, 26 Apr 2010 11:20:06 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  5244
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=96
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Request Headersview source
Host    www.euroworker.no
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; nb-NO; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100315 Firefox/3.5.9 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language nb,no;q=0.8,nn;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  300
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://www.euroworker.no/checkout/pay
Cookie  PHPSESSID=f5bd84668603decd779c5945d2de045c; __utma=259297566.1176642152.1271066660.1272267705.1272280025.34; __utmz=259297566.1271066660.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=259297566.7.10.1272280025; __utmc=259297566
```

When I click on HTML for the GET order tab, it appears to be getting the Leveringsmåte TD from the previous page and just adding it in there.

Comment: Can you show the HTML source code? What happens if you don't use the gzipping? This is probably some variable being overwritten, or not being properly cleaned up, at some point.

Comment: @Pekka, I wouldn't know which code excerpt to show you.. I could upload the HTML of the produkt page for you.

Comment: @Kyle where is the HTML code generated that you are showing above? The smarty template snippet responsible for that might be a start.

Comment: @Kyle so you're saying there is no HTML source code containing `Leverings...` when you view the page's source? Just so I understand you right.

Comment: @Pekka, that's exactly right.

Comment: @Kyle now that's mysterious. How about Firebug? Can you see where that text is in the DOM tree?

Comment: Found it in DOM Inspector.. `<TD class="amount shippingAmount">138.-</TD>`

Comment: Is there any place where this could come from? If it's not in the HTML source, could it have been loaded by AJAX? Does the "net" tab in Firebug give any indication?

Comment: It comes from the Complete page, the last page before you click pay for, there is a TD with the `Leverings...`The NET tab gives no indication.

Comment: Ok, refrehsed and NET gives this, shall post in UPDATE

Comment: Really strange. My bet would be a PHP or - more likely - JavaScript variable not getting cleaned up, but I don't really know. Hmm.

Comment: There isn't much Javascript linked to this to display the Delivery price, I think it's something in the PHP.. Is there something I can add to the produkt page to see if the leveringsmåte `TD` is there and hide it if it is?

Comment: @Kyle hmm, you could add a CSS rule `td.amount.shippingAmount { display: none }` but I would recommend to look for the root of the problem, you never know what else it may cause elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I need a quick fix for today, then after the page is launched I can hunt for the root.. Plus I am not the designer or manager of the functionality of the site. It's built upon a Lithuanian design at Livecart.com.

Comment: @Pekka, I added the CSS rule to a `style` tag in the `.tpl`. It's hiding it for now and I've sent a support request to the system designers. Thanks for all your help, if you want to make an answer out of all you've done, I'll accept as a bump to your rep. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to leave a quick update when it comes out what caused it. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments above:

If the mystery line is not in the HTML source code, but shows up in Firebug's DOM, then it is likely it gets injected there through Ajax somehow. My guess would be a not properly reset variable somewhere, either on the PHP or the JS end.

I guess there will be no way around step-by-step debugging to find out the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. Helped a great deal! I'll be sure to keep this updated as to what caused it and how to solve.

Comment: @Kyle yes, please do. You never know when that knowledge may come in handy.